# prevent user to type non-english characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this one to prevent user to type special chars.

```
String.prototype.isText = function () {return /^[\w\s]*$/.test(this)}
```

How can i change it to prevent users to type non-english words ? (only apostrophe and `&` will be accepted as special char)

Comment: Meu Deus. Don't forget to collect your Nobel Prize, when you're done with this task :)

Comment: got my prize and i am happy, are you ?

Comment: @Ahmet Voce sabe detectar os palavras nas outras línguas? Verdade? :)

Comment: Ich hab zwar keine Ahnung was Nikita sagen moechte, aber ich glaube ja auch dass dies hier das RegExp passed :P

Comment: Are you really trying to make sure the user can only enter words from the English language? If you are, you should use Andrew M's suggestion and blog about it once you get it working

Comment: @Ahmet: Jag undrar hur du funderat nu. Ett enkelt regexp kan inte detektera engelska ord, eller svenska, norska, danska, tyska etc som skrivs med det latinska alfabetet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regexp:

```
/^[a-z\s'&]*$/i
```

Comment: I see you marked this as the correct answer, so you don't really care that the non-English words are not allowed. What you do care is non-English characters. Please update the title of your question to reflect it. And this regex will fail for numbers, and capital letters. What you had was more elegant, just needed two extra chars: /^[\w\s&']*$/

Comment: Oops, true, I forgot `/i` for capital letters.

Answer (score 4):

Enforcing English with a regular expression? That's a rather naïve approach, and I'm not sure you'd want to include it on your résumé even if you did manage it. I'm not even sure I'd brag about it at the neighborhood café.

Believe it or not, there are a lot of English words (words that have been completely incorporated into the English lexicon) that are properly spelled with characters that don't match `/[a-z]/gi`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like this:
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Detect

That is a little bit over complicated if you just want to use regex to detect latin characters, but it will ensure it is actually English.